# C# сравнить порядок элементов в списках list1, list2

Tags: c#, list

Есть два списка list 1 и list 2 в них хранятся данные из БД. Как мне сравнить данные и сделать перестановку, если в порядок элементов 1-ого и 2-ого списка не совпадали. Например 3 записи в 1-ом спсике и в 2-ом тоже 3. Они сопадают. А должно в первый list 1 выводится записи в обычном порядке(как было), а во второй (list2) как угодно но не как в list 1

Comment: Вопрос был непонятен, но и после правки (попавшей в грейс-период) не прибавилось ясности. Вписывайте ещё примеры, что именно нужно - пока могу только проголосовать за закрытие вопроса, как плохосформулированного.

Comment: Кажется вы себе противоречите в вопросе, вам необходимо, чтобы элементы list2 были переставлены в тот же порядок как и в list1 или наоборот?

Comment: Так и трансформатор сгореть может, два раза читал ничего не понял, думаю вместо листов лучше использовать `Dictionary` в вашем случае.